# Workflow vs DFD vs Flowchart

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, uml

Why we use **Workflow** Diagram instead of **Data Flow Diagram (DFD) and Flowchart**. Whats are the basic difference among

> Workflow vs DFD vs Flowchart

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: May be DFD focus on Data, Flowchart focus on Process of a system & Workflow focus on Work. am i currect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding DFD vs Flowchart see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703948/what-is-the-difference-between-a-data-flow-diagram-and-a-flow-chart)

A workflow combines actions and object flows in a single diagram. The [Business Process Model and Notation](http://www.bpmn.org) is the most recent branch for noting a workflow.